# AWS S3 Bucket Policy to allow read-only access from my instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Is it possible to create an S3 bucket policy that allows read-only access from my EC2 instances? I tried a bunch of things, but I can't figure out what to use for the principal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principal will be the role.

i.e: arn:aws:iam::accountnumber:role/rolename

This post describes how to do it:

http://www.tothenew.com/blog/role-based-s3-access-from-a-specific-ec2-instance/

just ignore the part about the IP address since you won't need it.

Comment: Yup, this worked, but only when using the exact role name. I wonder if there's a way to use a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

You should be assigning your instances a role that allows access to your S3 bucket.

Comment: Yup, all my instances have a role. What I can't figure out is what to use for the principal in the bucket policy. I've been trying things like `arn:aws:iam::<id>:instance-profile/*` and `arn:aws:iam::<id>:role/*`, but everything I think should work is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that:

1. You need both the role itself and the assumed-role in your
   not_principals clause
2. wildcards are not allowed in principal
   specifications

This explains how to use userid instead:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/